# JavaScript returning var in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, canvas, for-loop

I am trying to understand code which implements canvas/context objects. This code returns an object if the sprite of that object is encountered on the canvas at a specified set of coordinates provided by a mouse button down event (as far as I can tell). 
Does the following code create an array of objects?

```
var selObj = getObjectByPixel(mx,my);
```

and

```
function getObjectByPixel(x,y) {
  gctx.clearRect(0,0,MaxX,MaxY);
  //alert(levelData.world['ExtraBlockTNT_1'].name);
  for (var objname in levelData.world) {
    var obj = levelData.world[objname];
    var sprd = spriteData[obj.definition];
    if(!sprd) continue;
    var tr = transform(obj.x, obj.y, sprd.data.width, sprd.data.height);

    gctx.save();
    gctx.translate(tr.x,tr.y);      
    gctx.rotate(obj.angle);

    gctx.fillRect(-tr.w/2, -tr.h/2, tr.w, tr.h);
    gctx.restore();
    //console.info(x,y);
    var imageData = gctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
    if (imageData.data[3] > 0) {
      return obj;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

It would seem to me that the first object in the loop will return if pixel data is encountered. If that is the case, does the loop end (which is what I assume will happen) or does it keep returning objects and store them in `selObj`

I'm quite confused by this code but the app runs without error so I must not be fully understanding it.

Thanks.

Comment: If the loop ends at the return (which is what I was almost sure of) then can someone make more sense of the logic than I am able to.

Answer (score 2):

It does not return an array. It returns an object, see: `return obj;`. You can only return from a function once.

p.s. if the author of this code was to return an array he would have probably called it: getObjectsByPixel (note the **s**).

Comment: That is exactly what I thought. Its just I can't make sense of the code if it only returns one object.

Comment: Would you agree that the loop returns the first object in levelData.world regardless of it sprite coordinates if pixel data is encountered at the mouse down coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

`return` *always* ends the execution and returns to the stack at the point the function was entered.

So that means it is only returning a single object.  In order to return an array, the function would have to first create the array, and then return it after the loop has finished.

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked out the dynamic of the block. The loop does only return a single `obj` (which  is what I knew anyway). The logic is, for every object sprite on the canvas, an invisible filled rectangle is created in a overlayed canvas until the mouse click coordinates are within the bounds of one of the rectangles. Then the object that that rectangle was generated from is returned.